# How to copy data from Amazon AWS S3 Bucket into a MariaDB SQL table in Apache Airflow

Tags: amazon-s3, mariadb, airflow, mariasql

In Airflow I know that you can use SQLToS3Operator to copy data from an SQL database to an S3 bucket, but I need it to go the other way; copying data from an S3 bucket into an SQL database. This would specifically be copying keys into a table, one key per table, into a locally hosted MariaDB SQL database just on my computer through Docker. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [S3ToMySqlOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/mysql/transfers/s3_to_mysql.py#L30) which works with mariadb too.